# InDesign: Export with SVG in spot colors

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, svg, color-profile, color-spaces

My Indesign document needs to be printed with a spot color. I have a svg-logo which is supposed to have this exact spot color.

It seems that I have no control over the color of the svg?

How can I print (=export) an InDesign document with only one color, if I have a svg-logo in it?

Comment: Your SVG does **not** have "this exact spot color".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVG documents can only be in RGB as far as I know. They can be automatically converted to CMYK on export from InDesign, but you can't export to a spot color like that.

I would either:

- Open the SVG in Illustrator. Change the colors to the wanted spot color. Save as an AI or PDF file and relink in InDesign.
- Open the SVG in Illustrator. Select the logo and copy it to clipboard. Paste it into InDesign and choose the wanted spot color.